# Is there an unambiguous stationarity test for time series?

Tags: time-series, unit-root, stationarity

It seems to me that the time series plot, the correlograms (ACS, PACS) and the "autocorrelation check for residuals test" can all be subject to interpretation.

(I am using SAS 9.4)

Is there an unambiguous way to determine whether a time series is stationary or not?

Comment: "Is there a unambiguous way to determine whether a time series is stationary or not?"...No, but there are formal statistical tests for stationary or a.k.a "unit root tests".  Popular unit root tests include the Augmented Dickey Fuller and KPSS tests.  There are many others which differ in how their null and alternatives are defined.

Comment: How are these things subject to interpretation (except for visual inspection of the time series plot)? They are hard facts characterising the data at hand, not opinions. If a test's $p$-value is 0.001 and your pre-chosen significance level is $\alpha=0.05$, is there still room for interpretation?

Comment: Just as _no_ statistical test can prove beyond a reasonable doubt that a coin is fair, there is no _unambiguous_ way to determine whether a time series is stationary or not. Hypothesis testing in the sense of Fisher never _accepts_ the null; one either _rejects_ the null or _does not reject_ the null. But not rejecting the null is not the same as affirming the null. A jury verdict of "Not guilty" does not mean that the defendant did not commit the crime, but only that the evidence submitted is not sufficient to support the indictment.

Answer (score 2):

Use unit root tests: Augmented Dickey Fuller (ADF), KPSS. There are many of these tests in R.

Comment: Can ADF etc be used on a time series which has been manipulated (e.g if we have taken the first- or second differerence?)

Comment: Yes, absolutely

Comment: KPSS test is not a unit root test.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't, as pointed out by user Dilip Sarwate.

You should also be aware of the "observational equivalence" of $I(0)$ and $I(1)$ processes: see Hamilton's 'Time Series Analysis' (section 15.4 on p. 444 and also p. 515)

Roughly this means that one can always find an $I(0)$ process that in finite samples resembles a $I(1)$ process.

Comment: +1 but would be nice to have the page number from Hamilton. Thanks.

Comment: @GraemeWalsh I have edited my answer and added the page references as suggested.